# w32time provider dll configured incorrectly? - fails being loaded by w32time with "access denied" error

Tags: c++, windows, dll, service, time

I'm at my wits end with this super descriptive "Access denied" error. Here's the rundown so far. Please keep in mind there is A LOT of information, so I may leave some out by accident.

- I am writing a time provider for the w32time service, this is NOT sysadmin stuff, it's not fixed by registering /unregistering the service
- I suspect my dll is not configured correctly in such a way to produce the "Access Denied" error

Here's what I've done to try and figure out what's wrong with my dll:

-Ran it through depends and all required callback functions are exposed [(TimeProvOpen, TimeProvClose, TimeProvCmd)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- All permissions of the dll and it's whole directory hierarchy are read/write/modify now
- Put some logging in the dll - nothing logs, meaning TimeProvOpen doesn't even get called!
- I am most definitely administrator

I'm not sure what else to do. I enabled debug logs for the Windows Time Service and it is no more descriptive. Just says:

Starting 'mytimeprovider', dll: 'path'

Logging error: Time Provider 'mytimeprovider' failed to start due to the following error: Access is denied (0x80070005)

What else should I be looking for? What can cause access denied, even when permissions are good, and callback functions are exposed?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a fabricator of some atomic time sync device with your computer why go through all this trouble ?.

I mean w32tm.exe can already sync with the tcp time protocol with other ip based time servers on the internet. the protocol is adjusting computer clock time depending on time gap, and can ignore to large gaps (or you can disable that). Just beter just be an ip based time source so you dont need to change the service itself (well i cannt imagine why someone would)

For your device, simply you could let it talk over tcp/ip in the same protocol as used by w32tm.exe service. You probaply could do that with an arduino, or pic, disbanding the whole windows OS and have a smaller clock device to sell.

BTW this service can keep track on multiple time services so its not so easy to fool.

Or wrap around time.exe to simply set the time

Comment: I am doing exactly that. Writing a time provider for a highly accurate input currently not supported on this machine. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Ok, might it be that you need to program it as a service (local system account), services can run under it, but people (normally) cant run code under that account as they cannt login into that account. Time itself can be changed by admin accounts, but changing it internal behavior might require even more permissions and under a different different credential (system acount).. its just a thought. Even an Admin has not the rights the system acount has, he's like the inner MS god on a machine (but has no network remote permissions).

Answer (score 0):

So my dll depends on a another static library built by an associate. As far as I can tell, my permissions issues are coming from there. When the other library is excluded, my dll is able to be loaded by the w32time service. I'm still trying to figure out how to include that other dll without errors.

At least it wasn't my fault, yay!